# Can I update a value of a key in a hash table?

Tags: hashtable

I am new to using hash table, and I want to know how to change the value of a specific existing key in a hash table. I tried to search but all that came up involved hash map, which I am not familiar with, and which I am not planning to use.

I am not sure whether hash tables only enables inserting and removing values, or whether it enables making a change to an existing key.

Also, please explain to me how to do so. (i.e. .put() means insert. what do I do to change?)

thanks.

Comment: "Hash table" and "hash map" are basically the same thing.  Generally the same `put` call that inserts a value will also overwrite an existing value.

Answer (score 0):

*Edited* because, on reflection, the wording of the question seemed ambiguous, and  might have assumed the wrong meaning initially.

You *can't* change the key, if that's what you meant.  The key determines the position of an entry in the hash map/table (by definition), so if you change the key without changing the position, the map/table is now corrupt.

To change the key and change its position is simple: remove the entry under the old key, and add the same entry under the new key.

You *can* change the value associated with the key. There are several possible approaches.  One is to just use put() with the same key to update the value; see the documentation for this. Another is to use entrySet() to get the set of key,value mappings, find the entry for your key, and use setValue() on that entry.

Of course, remove and re-add will also allow you to change the value.